# I lose history when load new url

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, webview

I have two `ViewController`, one of them has a `WebView` and calls to the second `ViewController`.

The second `ViewController` is a `QRReader` segue to the first `ViewController` with new URL.

My problem is that when I load the new URL, I clear the `WebView` history, so `GoBack` does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Store the current url in an array in `performSegueWithIdentifier` so when you segue back to the first view controller and the current URL changes, you can use `goBack` to load the most recent url in your array and so forth.

Comment: I think store current url is not enough, but Perhaps i can store a history vector and load when `goBack`. Do you know how can do that?. I searched on Google but no found a example. Thank you for your help!

Comment: What do you mean by vector? As in matrix vector calculations?

Comment: Sorry for my english, correct word is Array. Can I store a history array and load when `goBack`?. Thanks again

Comment: Yes, that's actually what I was trying to get across in my answer. Sorry if I was not clear enough :).

Comment: Do you know where can I found a example?. I read the official documentation and searched on Google, but I have not found.